# How to create columns with row counts in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataset where I am trying to count the values across rows, and then create different columns for the counts for each possible variable. I have a large dataset like this (thousands of rows):

| Date | Lat | Long | Station | Tow | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | y1 | x1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1990 | y1 | x1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1990 | y1 | x1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1990 | y1 | x1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1990 | y1 | x1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1990 | y2 | x2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1990 | y2 | x2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1990 | y2 | x2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1990 | y2 | x2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1990 | y2 | x2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

And I want to create a table like this in R

| Date | Lat | Long | Station | Tow | CountSex1 | CountSex2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | y1 | x1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1990 | y1 | x1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 1 |

I tried using group_by and summarize in tidyverse, but wasn't getting what I needed. I'm still really new to tidyverse and I cannot figure out what functions/combination of functions to use to get quite what I'm looking for.

What I tried:

```
countsex <- df %>% 
  group_by(Date, Lat, Long, Station, Tow, Sex) %>% 
  summarise(count_sex=n())
```

And I got:

| Date | Lat | Long | Station | Tow | Sex | CountSex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | y1 | x1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1990 | y1 | x1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1990 | y2 | x2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 1990 | y2 | x2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

which isn't what I'm looking for, and I couldn't figure out how to transform this to get what I needed.

Comment: There are a couple problems with your post that make this difficult to answer. First, `group_by()` changes the observation-level of the data, but does not remove anything. With rows containing `y2` and `x2` for `Lat` and `Long`, those will somehow appear after a `group_by() %>% summarize()` call, unless you filter them before. Second, the example outcome is unclear -- how did you get `CountSex1` and CountSex2`? What statistics are they intended to represent?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Sex, values_from = Sex, 
       values_fn = length, names_prefix = 'CountSex')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
   Date Lat   Long  Station   Tow CountSex1 CountSex2
  <int> <chr> <chr>   <int> <int>     <int>     <int>
1  1990 y1    x1          1     1         2         3
2  1990 y2    x2          1     2         4         1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L), Lat = c("y1", "y1", "y1", "y1", 
"y1", "y2", "y2", "y2", "y2", "y2"), Long = c("x1", "x1", "x1", 
"x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2"), Station = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Tow = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Sex = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach also using `pivot_wider`: Note `Sex` in `count`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  count(Date, Lat, Long, Station, Tow,Sex = paste0("CountSex", Sex)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Sex, values_from = n)
```

```
   Date Lat   Long  Station   Tow CountSex1 CountSex2
  <int> <chr> <chr>   <int> <int>     <int>     <int>
1  1990 y1    x1          1     1         2         3
2  1990 y2    x2          1     2         4         1
```